# SKSpriteNode position is not updating until next method is done running

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I run this code, the position of the SKSpriteNode sprite never updates (assuming it starts at some position other than 100, 100). If I remove the while loop in test2(), however, it updates immediately. Why is this? It seems like the while loop stops the sprite's position from updating, even though it should have no effect on it (it is in a completely different method which is called after the position is set)

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    test()
}

func test() {
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    test2()
}

func test2() {
    while (true) {

    }
}
```

Note: Obviously this is a very simplified version of the code, I was just wondering why the sprites behaved like this.

Comment: You are locking your main thread with test2, nothing will happen.

Comment: if you want something to repeat over and over you can put it in the `override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {` it will be called before each frame is rendered